# Python-3.5 typing.Generic subclass never calls `__init__`

Tags: python, generics, python-3.5

In the code below, I have a subclass of `Generic`. If I try to instantiate it after directly specifying the type (as in the case of `Bar`), it seems `__init__` is never called. See below for steps through in PDB.

```
from typing import Generic, TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T')
class Foo(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self, value: T):
        self.value = value

Bar = Foo[str]

foo = Foo('foo')
bar = Bar('bar')

print(type(foo), end=' ')
print(foo.value)

print(type(bar), end=' ')
print(bar.value) # AttributeError
```

According to the docs:

> The Generic base class uses a metaclass that defines **getitem**() so
>   that LoggedVar[t] is valid as a type:

Is this a bug, or have I not understood something?

**EDIT**

Stepping through in PDB for the Foo('foo') case, note `__init__` called at the end:

```
> /home/kjw53/test.py(1)<module>()
-> from typing import Generic, TypeVar
(Pdb) break /usr/lib/python3.5/typing.py:1078
Breakpoint 1 at /usr/lib/python3.5/typing.py:1078
(Pdb) c
> /usr/lib/python3.5/typing.py(1078)__new__()
-> return next_in_mro.__new__(_gorg(cls))
(Pdb) p cls
__main__.Foo[~T]
(Pdb) p next_in_mro
<class 'object'>
(Pdb) p _gorg(cls)
__main__.Foo[~T]
(Pdb) s
--Call--
> /usr/lib/python3.5/typing.py(858)_gorg()
-> def _gorg(a):
(Pdb) r
--Return--
> /usr/lib/python3.5/typing.py(863)_gorg()->__main__.Foo[~T]
-> return a
(Pdb) n
--Return--
> /usr/lib/python3.5/typing.py(1078)__new__()-><__main__.Foo...x7f57094b1a20>
-> return next_in_mro.__new__(_gorg(cls))
(Pdb) s
--Call--
> /home/kjw53/test.py(5)__init__()
-> def __init__(self, value: T):
```

Continuing on, now hitting the `Bar('bar')` case. Note `__init__` is not called, despite everything else relevant looking the same.

```
(Pdb) c
> /usr/lib/python3.5/typing.py(1078)__new__()
-> return next_in_mro.__new__(_gorg(cls))
(Pdb) p cls
__main__.Foo[str]
(Pdb) p next_in_mro
<class 'object'>
(Pdb) p _gorg(cls)
__main__.Foo[~T]
(Pdb) s
--Call--
> /usr/lib/python3.5/typing.py(858)_gorg()
-> def _gorg(a):
(Pdb) r
--Return--
> /usr/lib/python3.5/typing.py(863)_gorg()->__main__.Foo[~T]
-> return a
(Pdb) n
--Return--
> /usr/lib/python3.5/typing.py(1078)__new__()-><__main__.Foo...x7f57094b1a58>
-> return next_in_mro.__new__(_gorg(cls))
(Pdb) s
> /home/kjw53/test.py(13)<module>()
-> print(type(foo), end=' ')
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I have a class where one method inspects the annotations to the class's `__init__` method and instantiates those. So if the annotation is `Foo[str]`, this breaks. Looking at PDB I can't tell why it should. Is that useful without going into too much detail?

Comment: Would you not subclass with `class Bar(Foo["str"]):`?

Comment: In the test case that works. But that would mean creating an explicit sub-class for every case of the generic I use this way, which seems like it's defeating the point of having generics with annotations.

Comment: I would file a bug report, if there is some logic why this approach won't work then maybe some error or warning  should be raised,  if you explicitly call bar's init method it works fine and both foo and bar are `__main__.Foo` objects so there is no very obvious reason why ones init method would be called and the others is not.  The reason it fails is because of the logic in `_gorg`, if you just returned `a`  in _gorg or `next_in_mro.__new__(cls)` everything would work as so the heart of the issue lies there

Comment: Looking at the PDB steps, it seems like `_gorg` returns `__main__.Foo[~T]` for both cases. But I now have two people equally confused, so will report back about the bug report.

Comment: It does, if you copy Generic and _gorg from  https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Lib/typing.py and add some prints you can see exactly what is happening and why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just run it with Python 3.5.2 64bit on Windows, and it just works fine!
If it was a bug, it's fixed now.

Output:

- **main**.Foo<~T> foo
- **main**.Foo<~T> bar